# xskak spacing in styleC

Tags: xskak

Is it possible to control the spacing between the move number, white move and black move using styleC in xskak? I hve tried to read the documentation, but I couldn't find some hints.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}    
\usepackage{chessboard}           
\begin{document}              
\newchessgame
\mainline[style=styleC,level=1]{1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5}             
\end{document}
```

Comment: show a minimal example, that can be used for tests.

Comment: I have added a minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

styleC is made with a tabbing environment. You can copy the definition and change the values:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\xskaknewstyleitem[%
 opencommands={\begin{tabbing}%
    \hspace{.2\linewidth}%change
    \=\hspace{.2\linewidth}%change
    \=\hspace{.2\linewidth}%change
    \= \kill},
 closecommands={\end{tabbing}},
 blackopen=\>\ldots,
 beforenumber=\>,
 beforewhite=\>,
 beforeblack=\>,
 afterblack=\\]{styleC}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline[style=styleC,level=1]{1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5}
\end{document}
```

(As the default definition uses `\linewidth` the spacing changes if use is narrow environments. But you don't have to copy this -- I probably simply copied the value from the similar style in skak.)